# Building applications with multiple Rake files

Tags: ruby, rake

Is it at all possible to build multiple applications using multiple Rakefiles?

Any pointers to someone actually using Rake to build more than one application would be appreciated.

I have tried using import, but the variables in the separate Rakefiles seems to overwrite each other?

```
import 'application1/Rakefile'
import 'application2/Rakefile'

task :build => ['application1:build', 'application2:build']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WebYaST, the [main Rakefile](https://github.com/webyast/webyast/blob/e45363b0dba3b0c15f8857f3b51e4eb3e823881d/Rakefile) runs tasks from all subprojects, but in a separate rake process, via `system`.